# Storing file does not work in signed APK but works in debug APK

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to download the file locally in the device. I have enabled storage permission in the app. It works well in the debug APK. But when I tried with signed APK it is not working, the download does not take place.

**Here is my manifest code:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Here is my kotlin Permission code:**

```
    private fun askPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 100)
    } else {
    }
}
```

Why does this error happen and how can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error anywhere in logcat?

Comment: Basically it doesn't show up the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions?

Comment: @shkschneider no errors in logcat

Comment: @Heichou request permission is not asked in signed APK but was working fine in debug APK

Comment: It's the same android version (and device)?

Comment: yes same android device I only tried installing with signed apk and this problem is happening

Comment: If you try to add a log into the _else_ can you see it when you run the code in the signed? I would like to know it to check if the execution goes inside the _if_ or inside the _else_. If it goes inside the _else_ maybe could be a conflict (it's really hard, I don't think is possible but we will never know). In that case I would try the signed in an other device or try to uninstall the debug version

Comment: @Heichou you were right it is going to the else statement, so what is the problem how can I resolve this

Comment: @Heichou I tried performing in the else also and is working. Thanks dude

Comment: You're welcome, but I don't know if this is a properly solution workaround like this ahah. As I said, maybe could be a conflict between debugging up and signed app both installed on the same device. Maybe if the debugging grant the permission, the signed thinks it has the permission too, but inside Android this doesn't happen, that means you can't perform the next action (download). You should try the signed in an other _virgin_ device

Comment: yeah I should try that too

Comment: virgin device! hahahah